# How can I optimize this code?

Tags: theme-development, advanced-custom-fields, code

I have an Advanced Custom Fields Checkbox that I'd that I need to do some checks on. If a checkbox is ticked in the back end, it outputs an appropriate image on the front end. I've got some code that "works" but I think there's gotta be a much more efficient way to do it.

Here's the code

```
$gluten = 'gluten.png';
$vegan = 'vegan.png';
$vegetarian = 'vegetarian.png';
$dish = get_field('diet_friendly');

if( in_array( 'gluten', get_field('diet_friendly') ) )
 {
    echo '<img src="';
    echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/'.$gluten.'" alt="Gluten Free" />';
 }
if( in_array( 'vegan', get_field('diet_friendly') ) )
 {
    echo '<img src="';
    echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/'.$vegan.'" alt="Vegan Friendly" />';
 }
```

Here's the array of the checkbox field

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "gluten" [1]=> string(5) "vegan" }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning a value to `$dish`, but then not using it...

Try the following. It takes advantage of the fact that your image for "gluten" is named `gluten.png`, etc. You'll be able to add more tags by just adding to the `$images` array.

```
$images = array(
    "gluten"     => "Gluten Free",
    "vegan"      => "Vegan Friendly",
    "vegetarian" => "Vegetarian"
);
$dish_tags = (array) get_field('diet_friendly');

foreach ($images as $image_name => $alt) {
    if (in_array($image_name, $dish_tags)) {
        echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/' .
            $image_name . '.png" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! That works a treat alright! The problem is that if a checkbox is not selected then the following error pops up: **Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array**

Any thoughts there?

Comment: you could try casting `$dish_tags` as an array:

`$dish_tags = (array) get_field('diet_friendly');`

or wrapping your `foreach` in an `if` statement:

`if ( is_array( $dish_tags ) ) { /* foreach here */ }`